# How to get a lowercase &str vec?

Tags: string, vector, rust

I was wondering whether I could return a `Vec<&str>` type from my `to_lowercase()` below?

Here is my code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let str_list = vec!["hello", "hi", "ok"];
    println!("before: {:?}", str_list);

    let after = to_lowercase(str_list);
    println!("after: {:?}", after);
}

fn to_lowercase(str: Vec<&str>) -> Vec<&str> {
    str.into_iter()
        .map(|x| x.to_lowercase().as_str())
        .collect()
}
```

But, I got a compiler error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
  --> src\main.rs:11:18
   |
11 |         .map(|x| x.to_lowercase().as_str())
   |                  ----------------^^^^^^^^^
   |                  |
   |                  returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
   |                  temporary value created here
```

So, is there any solutions to fix this?

Comment: No. No one would own the new strings, you must return `Vec<String>`.

Comment: FWIW one option is to return a `Cow` if you can determine that the lowercase was a non-transformation. Though I don't think there's a great way to *make* that decision, currently, in the stdlib. The simplest would be to check for `char::is_lowercase` but I don't think it can handle the sigma special case (which `str::to_lowercase` does handle). That could save allocations, but at the cost of traversing every input twice. Whether that's worth it is basically down to how many inputs are already lowercase (and thus don't need transforming).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to return `Vec` of references.

```rust
fn to_lowercase(str: Vec<&str>) -> Vec<&str> { // `Vec` of references
}
```

You must ask yourself: references to WHERE/WHAT? Where that `str` may lay so you can return a reference to it?

In your `main` function your `Vec<&str>` is references to static strings in fact:

```rust
let str_list: Vec<&'static str> = vec!["hello", "hi", "ok"];
```

So `"hello"`, `"hi"` and `"ok"` are just dumped into your executable directly.

But when you perform any operation in runtime over that references where should result be held? The simplest way is to own it by `String` (what `to_lowercase` is exactly doing):

```rust
fn to_lowercase<S: AsRef<str>>(str: T) -> Vec<String> {
    str.as_ref()
        .iter()
        .map(str::to_lowercase)
        .collect()
}
```

Or (and better) you can return a raw iterator of results:

```rust
fn to_lowercase<S: AsRef<str>>(str: T) -> impl Iterator<Item = String> {
    str.as_ref()
        .iter()
        .map(str::to_lowercase)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The reason is that converting a Unicode String to lowercase/uppercase may need to reallocate the String, as case folding within Unicode might need more/fewer characters and/or bytes to encode the folded variant.

Either you can return a `Vec<String>`, where the new `String` holds the conversion. Or, if you are sure that your input is pure ASCII, you take use [`make_ascii_lowercase`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.make_ascii_lowercase) to do the conversion in-place; this has the downside that if proper Unicode folding requires more/less characters/bytes, no folding takes place.